# How to how to generate setters in doctrine?

Tags: php, doctrine

In symfony there is command to  generates getter/setter methods
 `php bin/console make:entity --regenerate App`

I use doctrine without symfony and want to generate setters for new attribures.  Is it possible with `orm:generate-entities`?

When I run command  `vendor/bin/doctrine orm:generate-entities /path --update-entities` it just create new folder `App\Entity\` in this path and generate all entities once again but without annotations.

And if I delete some files from that new generated entities, it create them again next time I run this command, but if I delete setters it doesn't recreate it,which I expect it to do.